# Disable Post Content in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently putting together a webcomic website. I have no need for post content / comments. Just looking to post a daily/weekly comic and leave it at that.

Current Site: http://anarchyplants.com

I've tried to disable the post edit box on the admin end as well as searched high and low on removing that "*Comments(0)*" on the mini nav bar.

Currently using Wordpress and ComicPress theme.
(http://comicpress.org/) w/ Comic Easel Plugin (it's required)

If someone more Wordpress versed that I can shed some light and teach me how to achieve this, I'd be more than grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable this from your css. Just place it in your child themes style.css file. It's not recommended that you remove the post edit box... How else would you publish your content?

```
/* Will hide the comments on the "mini navbar" */
#comic-nav-wrapper > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3){
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

To remove the content from the post, you could simply:

```
/* Remove the post content */
.post-content{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Splendid! - That CSS trick worked perfectly. Although, if you visit the site now, it seems to be off centered? - is that normal? 

As for the post edit box, Just hide it from the front page, not necessarily remove/delete it from the word press.

Comment: Beautiful. Truly elegant. Thank you much my friend. Quick note, the padding didnt seem to move it much? Should i increase or what have you?

Comment: can the padding be changed to center it more so? or does something have to be added? - sorry for pestering.

Comment: It is ok, you are not pestering me. I have replaced the first code set I provided. This should work to your liking now.